# having an iterative dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a database in which I registered some data. I tried to select all rows and try to put every row of my table into a dictionary, but I can't seem to do that.

This is the code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","aqw","PFE_Project" )
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM ServerComponents"

try:

   cursor.execute(sql)
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   nbre_row = cursor.rowcount

   server_name = []
   server_price = []
   for row in results:
      server_id = row[0] 
      server_name.append(row[1])
      core_number = int(row[2])
      clock_speed = int(row[3])
      ram = int(row[4])
      rom = row[5]
      hdd = int(row[6])
      video_card = row[7]
      cache_memory = row[8]
      # calculation metric is a function that i used to calculate the server prize
      p = calculations_metric (core_number, clock_speed, ram, hdd, video_card)
      server_price.append(p)

      try :
          # i wanna the attribute "response" be iterative
          response = {"Server Name" : server_name , "Server Price" : server_price }

      except :
          print "error in response"

except:
   print "Error: unable to fetch data"

print(response)
```

This is the result I got:

```
{"Server Name": ["Dell1", "Dell2"], "Server Price": [149, 151]}
```

But the result that I want see is like this:

```
{"Server Name" : Dell1, "Server Price": 149}
{"Server Name" : Dell2, "Server Price": 151}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
servers = []
for row in results:
   result = {}
   result['server_name'] = row[1])
   p = calculations_metric (core_number, clock_speed, ram, hdd, video_card)
   result['server_price'] = p
   servers.append(result)
```

Comment: this informations i need to parse them into json so i need to be the result as a dictionanry not a list of dictionaries so i can get the the keys(servername,server price) and their values
help please

Comment: Er, no, I can't, because that makes no sense. You originally had a dictionary, and requested help getting a list of dictionaries instead. So now I can't understand what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","aqw","PFE_Project" )
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM ServerComponents"

response = []
try:

   cursor.execute(sql)
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   nbre_row = cursor.rowcount

   for row in results:
      local_dict = {}
      server_id = row[0] 
      local_dict["Server Name"] = row[1]
      core_number = int(row[2])
      clock_speed = int(row[3])
      ram = int(row[4])
      rom = row[5]
      hdd = int(row[6])
      video_card = row[7]
      cache_memory = row[8]
      # calculation metric is a function that i used to calculate the server prize
      p = calculations_metric (core_number, clock_speed, ram, hdd, video_card)
      local_dict["Server Price"] = p
      response.append(local_dict)


except:
   print "Error: unable to fetch data"

print(response)
```

Instead of appending to list, we are creating local dict and adding that local dict to response.

Comment: this informations i need to parse them into json so i need to be the result as a dictionanry not a list of dictionaries so i can get the the keys(servername,server price) and their values help please

Comment: Dictionary will take `key, value` pair, for to store value without any key you have to use list or tuple. List and tuple are order data structure.